# Sites com separação silábica e sílaba tónica

Tags: discussion, recursos

Procuro um site que faça ou tenha a separação silábica com sílaba tónica das palavras em português.

Comment: Encontei [este](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=syllables&act=list&search=cede) que tem poucas palavras e [este](https://www.separarensilabas.com/index-pt.php) que é lento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não acho uma lista completa para a tonicidade, mas alguns dicionários são recursos úteis. Por exemplo, a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/palavra) mostra a separação na translineação, e a tonicidade na fonética (com uma plica, ' , que antecede a sílaba tônica):

> pa.la.vra - pɐˈlavrɐ"

e o [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/palavra) mostra a sílaba tônica em itálico já na separação silábica:

> (pa.*la*.vra)

Contudo, como o bad_coder explicou em comentários, para conjugações de verbos irregulares encontrar a tonicidade é um desafio (há [regras](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/formas-rizotonicas-e-arrizotonicas/) para os regulares), então esta não é uma resposta completa.